# JavaFX button handle() not calling methods

Tags: java, events, javafx, label

This seems like it is a very basic issue and that the answer is right in front of me, but I still can't figure out what's wrong. I have a button, and when handling the click event I change the style and text of a Label. After that, I call a method which changes the style once again when finished.

My problem is that the style changes in the handle() method does not affect my label, and instead it goes straight from its default style to the style set by connect().

Mind you that it's not because it changes too fast, the connect() method usually takes a full second or so to complete as it connects to a remote server.

I tried sleeping the thread for a second (in case my were too slow) inbetween setStyle() and connect(), but to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any help, and hopefully learn something along the way.

This is my code:

```
Button loginButton = new Button();

    loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            loginStatus.setText("Loggin in...");

            //The line below should change the color until connect does it's thing, but it doesn't
            loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#ffcc00"); 

            connect(username.getText(), password.getText(), serverField.getText());
        }
    });
```

And connect() looks like this:

```
private void connect(String username, String password, String server) {
    try {
        api = new DiscordBuilder(username, password).build();
        api.login();
        api.joinInviteId(server);
        api.getEventManager().registerListener(new ChatListener(api));

        //Instead, it goes straight from the old style to the style set below.
        loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#009933");

        loginStatus.setText("Online");
    } catch (NoLoginDetailsException e) {
        loginStatus.setText("No login details!");
        loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#cc3300");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadUsernamePasswordException e) {
        loginStatus.setText("Bad username or password!");
        loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#cc3300");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DiscordFailedToConnectException e) {
        loginStatus.setText("Failed to connect!");
        loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#cc3300");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

also as stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

> Implementing long-running tasks on the JavaFX Application thread
>   inevitably makes an application UI unresponsive. A best practice is to
>   do these tasks on one or more background threads and let the JavaFX
>   Application thread process user events.

so your code should look like this

```
    Button loginButton = new Button();
    loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            loginStatus.setText("Loggin in...");
            //The line below should change the color until connect does it's thing, but it doesn't
            loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#ffcc00"); 
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    connect(username.getText(), password.getText(), serverField.getText());
                    return null;
                }
            };
            new Thread(task).start();
        }
    });
```

and in your connect method surround your ui updating methods with `Platform.runLater`

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    loginStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:#009933");
    loginStatus.setText("Online");
}) ;
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I am experiencing thread errors when an exception is called in the connect() method. If no Exceptions are thrown then there is  no problem, since I moved the setStyle of the "successful" outcome as you showed. But how would I go about handling the exceptions without getting "Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4"?

Comment: I changed connect() to return a boolean so that I can move the setStyles out of the catch clauses aswell. It stops the thread exceptions but won't tell me what kind of exception was thrown. I feel like I'm getting close to a solution, any ideas?

Comment: ok, I edited my answer not to throw exceptions about updating ui in non FX app threads...

Comment: Again, thank you! I happened to solve it at the same time as you posted, but I chose to make connect() return different String arrays, and i use the Strings returned in the call() method under Platform.runLater() just once instead (setStyle(statusArgs[0]) for instance). I don't know if I'm making sense, but I hope you understand what I mean. Is this a worse practice than what you showed me?